# Where can I find an 8086 chip?

Tags: microprocessor, system-on-chip

sometime ago I built an emulator for the 8086 chip and now I'm wanting to actually own one and set one up for some bit banging and such. Note, I'm not interested in all the PC specifics(DMA, PIC, BIOS, etc) only the bare basics to get the 8086 to run some code, which as I understand only requires a power supply, oscillator/clock source, and some RAM(unknown which type?)

So, for the most part all of the components are easy to find except for the one I need: The 8086 processor itself. I've not been able to find anything but (very pricey) collector's items 8086 chips. So where can I find a reasonably priced replica 8086 chip? Note: The pin out doesn't need to be the exact same, but I'd prefer it to be DIP and expose all of the features of the 8086. Also, don't just say "try buying an old 486 computer" After the 8086, the x86 line of processors got insanely complex. For this reason, I'm sticking to just the 8086. Though possibly an 8186 would be OK.

Also, if there is a system-on-chip type 8086 setup, that'd be awesome. (Note, I'm just talking about a chip that includes the RAM  and possibly some flash ROM on it)

Comment: Your problem is that unlike 80186 or 80386, 8086 was discontinued early in the 90s and it wasn't as popular at the time.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the 8088 from futurlec.com for about $4.  Its an 8086 with an 8-bit external bus.

Try searching for "NEC v20" which was an 8086 clone that was popular.

The 80186 is the embedded system-on-chip equivalent, there's tons of variants of that still in use.

Comment: Ah, the NEC V-series!  I had a lot of fun with those!

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://opencores.org/project,zet86) is an 80186 FPGA emulation, using it might be easier than finding real silicon. It even runs Windows! You can strip out all the stuff you don't need, if you just want to run some 80186 code.

Comment: That's probably a full PC emulation, not just the CPU. Interesting nonetheless because I have an FPGA sitting on my desk. The gate count is probably too low for such a thing though

Answer (score 1):

I just found КР1810ВМ86 on [e-bay](http://cgi.ebay.com/KR1810VM86-Soviet-CPU-Clones-Intel-8086-/180636103907) for sale. It should be pin compatible.

Comment: The funny thing is that I believe KP1810 & KP580 are still being produced here in exUSSR. My home signalization is using one of them, and it is brand new :-) Crazy things :-)

Comment: @BarsMonster  I've been looking in stocks of some sellers and I've seen them with date codes of year 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of [these vendors that say they have it in stock](http://octopart.com/partsearch/#search/requestData&q=8086&filters%5Bmanufacturer%5D%5B%5D=Intel&rangedfilters%5Bavg_avail%5D%5Bmin%5D=1&rangedfilters%5Bavg_avail%5D%5Bmax%5D=null).  The 8186 might be tougher to find.

Answer (score 0):

Jameco currently has both the 8086 and the 8088.

FYI, questions like "where can I buy..." generally do not belong here, but *shrug*.